# Why does Google, in it's Page Insights tool, advise to use WebP images which don't work in all browsers?

Tags: images, performance, page-speed, optimization

I recently swapped all of the images on my web with WebP compressed images and the Page Insights score got as high as 97. However, I found out my page doesn't work on IE, Safari and Firefox (all other major browsers besides Edge and Chrome).

So why would Google give out such ill-advised information?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reminder! ♥

Comment: Perhaps Google is expecting us to use the < picture > element to choose webp images, then provide a jpg fallback. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since WebP is an efficient file format, and Google serves up a lot of images to users, Google has a vested interest in getting WebP supported by all major browsers so that they no longer have to serve up less efficient JPG and PNG images.

The best path to get WebP supported by browsers is to get a large proportion of websites on the internet to use it. But the only way browsers (Safari) will feel pressure to add support for it is if websites already use it. It's a chicken-and-egg problem.

By fudging the truth and recommending WebP even though it's unsupported by Safari, Google is hoping to force Safari's hand into not being able to ignore it anymore. In other words, they're trying to force Safari to implement WebP as a response to the increasing number of websites using it.

**In short, Google is recommending WebP not because it necessarily makes sense to a webmaster right now, but because it's in Google's own financial interest as it would reduce their bandwidth costs if widely supported.**

Now, I believe that in this case Google's financial interests align with the interests of the general internet-browsing public. WebP is a fine image format that would save *everyone* a lot of bandwidth and storage, and I'm just as annoyed that Safari is the last major browser to not support it.

So to answer your question, the reason Google is giving out ill-advised information is a combination of (1) financial incentive, (2) optimism that they can pressure Safari to implement it and thus the soundness of the WebP recommendation will be a self-fulfilling prophecy, and (3) in a very Google fashion, their page insights tool not being updated since several years ago, back when it still looked like WebP had an imminent chance at becoming a universal web image format.

Answer (score 1):

Webp is not supported on Internet Explorer (which ended in version 11 and will soon be unsupported, as 10 already is). Microsoft is pushing Edge which supports webp, and now  edge is even based on chromium.

Firefox supports webp, maybe you are having a different issue there?

The Safaris, on the other hand, don't at all.

[You can check all of this and more at Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp)

Using webp when Safari users can not handle that image format is something to be taken into account in general, I agree.

Internet explorer, on the other hand... it depends on your audience.

Your mileage may vary in regards to browser use, in general terms [you can see that it is basically all about Chrome and Safari](https://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php). Remember that in that graph Edge and Internet Explorer are combined and for your purpose that is misleading.

And it is also a matter of your philosophy, the role your webp images play in your website, the tradeoff between SEO, speed and experience, etc.

All in all, what Page Insights says, is just:

> Image formats like JPEG 2000, JPEG XR, and WebP often provide better
>   compression than PNG or JPEG, which means faster downloads and less
>   data consumption.

[More information on this.](https://web.dev/uses-webp-images/)

They refer to webp as next-gen formats. Again, is one way of considering support towards the future (webp is more like the past already) over broad compatibility.

And/or browser wars: Apple not adding webp support and Google ignoring Safari users.